# Ruby on Rails 4 - Form helper not passing a params hash to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, formhelper

I'm having some issues with my view not passing a params hash to the controller. I have a form defined in a view that will add a new item to a database and I am getting the error:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing:
  param not found: item
```

Here are my code files for the form helper in question and my controller that handles the action.

**new.hmtl.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@item) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>

  <%= f.label :description %>
  <%= f.text_field :description %>

  <%= f.submit "Add", class:"btn btn-large btn-primary %>
<% end %>
```

**items_controller.rb**

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @item = Item.create(set_params)
  end

  private
    def set_params
      params.require(:item).permit(:name, :description)
    end
  end
end
```

I've yet to see a solid answer on how to fix this from the other questions I've seen, I think.

Comment: You need to add in a create action that has `def create @item = Item.create(set_params) end    let the new action be def new @item = Item.new end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `new` action is the one that renders the form to create a new Item. When this action is rendered, your params are blank.

Your `create` action is the one that processes the form, where your params will be populated.

Comment: Hm, I did that before but I think I was mixed up somewhere. Anyway, this fixed it, thanks!